# ActiveModel form using fields_for in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an ActiveModel "form object" which "has many" patients (another ActiveModel "form object"). The idea being the user can fill in the form and add as many patients.

```
- @form.patients.each do |patient|
  = form.fields_for 'patients[]', patient do |patient_form|
```

This worked fine in Rails 4 and as far as I remember inputs where named something like `patients[][name]`.

This was an Array in `params` such as `{ patients: [ {name: 'foo'} ] }`.

However it seems this may have changed with Rails 5, looking at [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1957) it seems if name ends in `[]` and there is no index given it will try and insert an id.

Giving an input name such as `patients[1][name]`.

However the form object (ActiveModel) has no `#id` method and I get an `NoMethodError`. And even if it did this would give a `params` has which would be a Hash such as `{ patients: { '1' => { name: 'foo' } } }`.

If I just do `form.fields_for 'patients', patient` all input have the same name and thus overwrite each other in `params`.

Comment: Ok, this question is very confusing as it doesn't contain everything that we need to understand what's going on. What is it you are actually trying to do? Can you show us the code/form you have written (all of it, not just a tiny sub-snippet), and the (R4) code you wrote that accepts the params? Also show us an example of what used to come through and what now comes through on the params hash? (full example, not just sub-snippets)... and we can help you to write code that will parse the new params set, or rebuild your form to provide the output you really want.

Comment: I'll try and add more detail, I didn't want to add too much code as it gets confusing too :) I guess to summarise I want `fields_for` to create inputs which are named `patients[][name]` not `patients[1][name]`. I can't really undertsand why `fields_for` does this since new models will not have an id anyway.

Comment: Sure too much code is bad, but zero code is also bad (it's really hard to debug a verbal description of code) ;) I don't know why they do the fake-id thing either - but it's never been a problem at the other end (ie once it arrives in the controller). Can you explain why it's an issue for you? What is the problem: what do you observe and what do you need instead (and why) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to add a "fake" #id method to the "form object":

```
# form object (ActiveModel)
def id
  SecureRandomn.hex(10)
end
```

This will give inputs named as such: `patients[f0858de30df23c3e2305][name]`.

Then in the controller I can convert the params hash (`{ id => attributes, id => attributes, ... }`) to an array of attributes (`[attributes, attributes, ...]`):

params[:patients].values

While I don't mind 'fixing' the params too much adding a useless #id method to the form seems too much.